# Киево-Печерские святые или киево-печерские святые?

Tags: прописная-строчная

«Киево-Печерские святые или киево-печерские святые»? Склоняюсь к варианту со строчными буквами...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Грамота](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=290243):

> Прилагательные, образованные от географических названий, пишутся с
> прописной буквы, если они являются частью составных наименований —
> географических и административно-территориальных, *индивидуальных имен
> людей* [выделение моё — N.].

В вашем случае географическое название входит в наименование группы людей. К примеру, пишется: ["Собор Валаамских святых"](https://drevo-info.ru/articles/26180.html), [Собор всех преподобных отцов Киево-Печерских](https://azbyka.ru/days/sv-sobor-vseh-prepodobnyh-otcov-kievo-pecherskih) и т. п. То есть эти прилагательные рассматриваются как фамилии, прозвища или титулы (ср.: патриарх Московский, патриарх Константинопольский).